# copy from PNG image coming as blank

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to copy a PNG photo to another place from this  but it is coming as black. I want to show a zoomed captcha in popup

Same code is working when site is changing at 11 am IST for 20 minutes daily.

What could be the problem?:

```
"use strict";


$("body").append(
        '<img id="anu-img-photo1" />'
        );

$("#cimage").load(function ()
    {
         ff_img_copy(document.getElementById('cimage'), document.getElementById('anu-img-photo1'));


    }).each(function ()
    {
        if (this.complete)
            $(this).load();
    });


function ff_img_copy(src, destination)
    {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = '#fff'; /// set white fill style
        canvas.width = src.width;
        canvas.height = src.height;

       // alert('w,h=' + src.width + '+' + src.height);

        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.drawImage(src, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        destination.src = dataURL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed this line:   `context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

then it's working fine as the image was PNG and because of transparency this problem was coming.